# removing backlash from sequence

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

How do I remove this running backlash from my sequences?

```
\ACCATTTTTTTATAGTGA
AGTACAGTAGATATAAACCCACCACAATAGGCTGAGGCTTCC\TTATCAATAGCTTGATT
TTGGAAATACGTAGAACCCCAATGTGGTCCAAAGCTACTTGGA\CATTGGTCAAAATCCA
AGTCACATTATCGTGACCATCTTAATCTTTACATTTTTCAAAAT\GCATGAACCTTTTTC
CTCAAAAATAGCTCTAATACTTTGCTCCTATTGCGGGTCCCACAA\TACAATTTAAATTT
TACCATAATTAAAGTTACCTTAAACTCTCCGAACCTCATATGTCAC\GAACTTGAAGTCG
TACCTTTTTCCAAGTCGGCCATGGTTCATCAAATTTTTGTCTAATGA\TCCATTAGAAGA
TAATGGAAGGGCCGTGTGCTGACGTAAATATATGGAAAATGATATTAT\CAATGTCATAT
TTAAAGAATGTTATTTAAGAAAATAACTATTATATTAAAATTTACTTAC\TCTTTGTCTA
TTGCTTGAAGAAAAGGACTTTTATCAATTGGATGATAAGAGTGTAGAGAT\AGGTATTCA
GGTATCAACGAATCTTCTAGTGCTGAAGGTGTGACCACTATAGAAGGTATA\ATGGAAAT
CGATTTGGCTACAAAGGTAGGCTTTGGTTCCTACTGAACCGTAGAAAATGTG\CCCTGTT
GGACAATAGGAATTGTTGACTCTAAGGTTGAGATGTGAATGGTAGAAGTGAGA\AAGTTG
ATGGTGGCTAGAGCTCTCCCACCAACACCATGACCTTTGCCATGGTTAGATGGT\CTACA
ACCATCACTTCTACCTCTGTCCATCATCTGTATGTAGAAATTGTTACATATATGA\CAAT
TCTAAGTGAACATAAATAAACAAAGTGAAATATTATATCTTTAGTAAAAAAGAAAG\TAA
CCCAACTTATGAGAGAAAACTCAAACTTGATCATTTTTTCTACACTAAAACGTGTCA\CT
TATCTTTTCCCTCATAATCACTACAAGTAATTATTACAAATAATGGTCATACAAATGT\A
```

Comment: if you just want to delete all backslashes, use `tr` command... also check out https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I suspect from the length of the first line and the alignment that the answer lies in _how you are generating them_  in the first place.  Of course, you give us zero information about that.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your txt to sed `'s@\\@@g'`

`sed 's@\\@@g' sq.txt > new.sq.txt`
**note**: remove `cat` command as per comments suggestion.

or using `cat sq.txt | tr -d '\\' > new.sq.txt`

Comment: The `cat` is definitely not needed.

Answer (score 1):

With `tr`:

```
tr -d \\\\ <file_in >file_out
```